# Tracking links within my site

Tags: google-analytics, hyperlink, tags, google-tag-manager, tracking

I want to track particular links on my site to see where they come from. For example, I want to know which links on my navigation are being clicked, so if something is not being clicked I could potentially remove it.

I have been using UTM's, super easy, but results in skewed analytics data.

I looked into Google Tag Manager, but I don't want to slow down my website. I can change the site easily, so not sure if this is the best solution.

I found an article dated 2008 that says I can do this:
https://www.example.com/?from=topnav

Is that still valid? Is there a better way. I can't seem to find any information on this and assume somebody wants to acquire this information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been using UTM's, super easy, but results in skewed analytics
>   data.

UTM codes are meant to track inbound traffic. Don't use them to track internal/outbound navigation, as it will seriously mess up your reporting.

> I looked into Google Tag Manager, but I don't want to slow down my
>   website.

GTM is loading async, just like GA, so performance-wise they are equivalent.

> I found an article dated 2008 that says I can do this:
>   https://www.example.com/?from=topnav

By default GA will not track link clicks. You can indeed add parameters to URLs and then use those to build custom reports and see which links are being clicked.

**Since what you're trying to do is custom implementation**, you won't find a single best answer, it's up to you to implement something that fits your needs. These are some examples:

- https://analytical42.com/2017/track-internal-links-google-analytics-gtm/
- https://www.gravitatedesign.com/blog/can-google-analytics-track-link-clicks/

Comment: I spent a day trying to implement Tag manager with no luck. If I add the ?from= to link will that affect the analytics in the same way the UTM does, or will Google track Organic/paid/etc traffic and ignore that parameter?